# XSLT 2.0 grouping based on more than one element

Tags: xslt

I have an xml like this,

```html
<Accounts>
 <Account>
  <AccNo>
   <Acc1>1</Acc1>
   <Acc2>2</Acc2>
  </AccNo>
  <AccItem>
   <AccItemDetail>Item1</AccItemDetail>
  </AccItem>
 </Account>
 <Account>
  <AccNo>
   <Acc1>3</Acc1>
   <Acc2>4</Acc2>
  </AccNo>
  <RefAcc>
   <AccNo>
    <Acc1>1</Acc1>
    <Acc2>2</Acc2>
   </AccNo>
  </RefAcc>
  <AccItem>
   <AccItemDetail>Item2</AccItemDetail>
  </AccItem>
 </Account>
 <Account>
  <AccNo>
   <Acc1>5</Acc1>
   <Acc2>6</Acc2>
  </AccNo>
  <AccItem>
   <AccItemDetail>Item3</AccItemDetail>
  </AccItem>
 </Account>
</Accounts>
```

Now I want to group all Account by concat(AccNo/Acc1,AccNo/Acc2) plus concat(RefAcc/AccNo/Acc1,RefAcc/AccNo/Acc1) if RefAcc exists. So in above xml the first 2 `<Account>` will be grouped together and AccItem will have both Item1 and Item2 i.e. resulting xml would be

```html
<Accounts>
 <Account>
  <AccNo>12</AccNo>
  <AccItem>
   <AccItemDetail>Item1</AccItemDetail>
  </AccItem>
  <AccItem>
   <AccItemDetail>Item2</AccItemDetail>
  </AccItem>
 </Account>
 <Account>
  <AccNo>56</AccNo>
  <AccItem>
   <AccItemDetail>Item3</AccItemDetail>
  </AccItem>
 </Account>
</Accounts>
```

How to achieve this in XSLT 2.0 in an efficient way considering there will be multiple `<Account>`?

Comment: **1.** Please fix your input to be well-formed XML. **2.** Why would the first two accounts be grouped together, when they have different `RefAcc` values (i.e. the first one doesn't have any)?

Comment: Xml updated. Yes the first Account does not have RefAcc since its optional but if it RefAcc exists then corresponding AccItem's should be attached to parent account. As you can see the output has Item1 and Item2 under AccNo 12.

Comment: That's still not clear. Are you trying to group based on **either** one of the `Acc1 & Acc2` combinations?